# How to have radio buttons in a Flex tree?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, menu, flex4, radio-button

I'm trying to get a tree to display some nodes as radio buttons.  Can anyone see why this is not working?  After I get it working with static XML I'll then need to make it from dynamic data too.

TY,
Fred

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="treeData">
        <node label="Interfaces">
            <node label="RS485 Port 1">
                <node label="Q I/O" type="radio" radioGroup="group1"/>
                <node label="BACnet MSTP" type="radio" radioGroup="group1"/>
                <node label="MODBUS RTU" type="radio" radioGroup="group1"/>
            </node>
            <node label="RS485 Port 2">
                <node label="Q I/O" type="radio" radioGroup="group2"/>
                <node label="BACnet MSTP" type="radio" radioGroup="group2"/>
                <node label="MODBUS RTU" type="radio" radioGroup="group2"/>
            </node>
            <node label="Ethernet Port 1">
                <node label="BACnet IP"/>
                <node label="BACnet SNMP"/>
                <node label="Modbus TCP"/>
            </node>
            <node label="Ethernet Port 2">
                <node label="BACnet IP"/>
                <node label="BACnet SNMP"/>
                <node label="Modbus TCP"/>
            </node>             
        </node>
        <node label="Devices">
            <node label="RS-485 Port 1">
                <node label="Quest I/O">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                    <node label="Universal Input 1">
                    </node>
                    <node label="Universal Input 2">
                    </node>
                </node>
                <node label="BACnet MSTP">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>                 
                <node label="MODBUS RTU">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node label="RS-485 Port 2">
                <node label="Quest I/O">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>
                <node label="BACnet MSTP">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>                 
                <node label="MODBUS RTU">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node label="Points">
            <node label="Inputs">
                <node label="Universal Input 1">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                    <node label="Front Door Sensor">
                    </node>
                </node>
                <node label="Universal Input 2">
                    <node label="Add...">
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node label="Outputs">
                <node label="Add...">
                </node>
            </node>
            <node label="Schedule">
                <node label="Add...">
                </node>
            </node>
            <node label="Calendar">
                <node label="Add...">
                </node>
            </node>
            <node label="String">
                <node label="Add...">
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:Tree id="myTree" width="762" height="100%" labelField="@label"
         showRoot="true" dataProvider="{treeData}" />
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the component that uses this `treeData` in your code. But in general I would use a List with an ItemRenderer that looks like a radio button.

Comment: I put some new sample code there, just trying to get some of the nodes to look and work as radio buttons.  Not sure why they're not rendering as radio buttons.  Mutually exclusive check boxes would also work.

Comment: I think this should help you http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a31/Flex-Checkbox-TreeItemRenderer.html

Comment: This answer about listItemRenderer may work for you by replacing linkbuttons with radioButtons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699977/link-button-in-tree-at-end-of-each-parent-node/5700155#5700155